# How to access statement text in Postgres trigger

Tags: postgresql

I'm attempting to put together what I thought would be a simple audit ability in Postgres.
I intend to log session_id/user_id etc., but what I'm really after is logging the actual statement, in full. I know I can get the operation with `TG_OP`, but does anybody know the secret sauce to get the actual text of the current statement?

Answer (score 4):

This information can be retrieved with the `current_query()`function.